# IIS 8.5 executionTimeout does not work MVC5

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8.5

**Environment:**
IIS 8.5 .NET Framework 4.7.2 ASP MVC5

**Goal:**
Drop requests incoming to IIS after the specified timeout.

**What we tried:**

*Set executionTimeout="10":*

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
<compilation explicit="true" optimizeCompilations="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" debug="false">
...
</compilation>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="10" maxRequestLength="53477376" maxWaitChangeNotification="20" shutdownTimeout="30" waitChangeNotification="20" maxQueryStringLength="4096" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
...
</system.web>
```

We expect the request to this endPoint to close in 10 seconds (We check here - IIS Manager - Worker Processes - Requests)

```
piblic async Get()
{
    await Task.Delay(4000);
}
```

But requests are still executed for 4+ minutes, and don't stop after executionTimeout = "10" (10sec) as expected.

**Why do we need this:**
The problem is that some of our non-critical requests processing too long, taking up the queue of requests on IIS.
This could be queries to MS SQL (they take a long time to process due to the possible presence of locks), or queries to external APIs.
We need terminate requests after a certain timeout, even if everything goes according to plan and the request works correctly, but we cannot wait any longer.

Comment: Did you test the timeout on localhost? to test timeout you should use "othername" instead of "localhost".

Comment: @samwu no - I used my test environment  - on test domain

Comment: Have you set <compilation debug="false">? The executionTimeout applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False.

Comment: @samwu   yes - compilation debug is false

Comment: Clear cache and try again. does the local executionTimeout work properly? Or does the problem only occur when published to iis? if so, in IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. Under Connection Limits option, you should set Connection Time-out.